# One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values: после смены версии implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'

Tags: java, android, android-gradle

После смены версии 1.4.2 зависимости

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
```

В gradle:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

Даже на чистом проекте, вновь созданном, выдаёт ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает без ошибок если только поставить старую версию

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А сама ошибка-то где?

Comment: Вангую, что новая версия зависимости хочет повышения версии SDK в проекте.